# viewmodel classes generation

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, code-generation, viewmodel

I'm using EF 4.1 in a Silverlight project and for a few reasons, I'm using WCF directly and not using RIA services. Now, the model entities generated by EF are attachable/detachable to datacontext and doesn't feel like it's a very good idea to be passing around different layers, especially to the view.

I have read up a little bit and I understand I can create my own classes (Q1. are these classes called ViewModel classes?) which have mostly auto properties and just some logic required for display and validatoin and I can use a library like auto-mapper to map back and forth between the EF entity and my (viewmodel??) class.

I was wondering is there a library/utility I can use to generate these class from EF entities? I have more than a handfull of entities with lots of properties that can change along the course of development and I'd hate to manually create these classes and change /maintain these whenever I have to change the EF model entities.

I hope it's clear what I'm asking; if not let me know and I'll try to elaborate a little bit more and/or post some examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A ViewModel is a "Model of a View".

Your ViewModel should expose the actual entity object(s) rather than it's individual properties. E.g. if you have a Customer entity with Forename, Surname and Age properties you would have a `Customer SelectedCustomer` property or `List<Customer> AllCustomers` property rather than Forename, Surname, Age etc.

You set your View's DataContext to an instance of the required ViewModel and use binding to view/update the various properties of the ViewModel, in this case Customer.Forename, Customer.Surname etc.

The ViewModel would implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface to raise messages when any of it's properties change, to notify the View of any changes and update the View.